# iOS app appears to still be in background after calling exit()

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to smoothly close down my app.

First I put the app in the background and tried to use `exit(0)` to close down the app:

```
//home button press programmatically
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app performSelector:@selector(suspend)];

//wait 2 seconds while app is going background
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];

//exit app when app is in background
exit(0);
```

My problem is, when I check to see what apps are running in the background, the app is still there. I thought `exit(0)` would remove it from the background.

It appears my app is going under recently used. Is there a way to programmatically remove it from that list?

Comment: Isn't it just there as one of the apps that user opened recently, but not exactly running? If you open it from there, does it seem to just start running or does it act like it was brought from background?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I check to see what apps are running in the background"? How are you checking this? The double-home-button-tap menu is not apps running, just recent apps.

Comment: This sounds like something that under no circumstances would be approved by Apple for the App Store.

Comment: It sounds like its going under recent apps. Is there away to remove my app from recents?

Comment: @remus as long as you put exit(0); in background handler... apple has no problems with it.

Comment: you must put exit('bundle_name') and can close whichever app you want :)

Comment: @NicolasManzini No, you can't. `exit` takes an `int` value. It's simply a result code. It has nothing to do with the app bundle name. And no, you can't terminate other apps.

Comment: really :) no jokes allowed in stack overflow?

Comment: It would make more sense to add the little-used key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` with a value of `YES` in your Info.plist.  This way, iOS will take care of exiting for you.  If your goal is to hide the fact the app was recently opened, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 8):

You can't programmatically remove an app from the "recently used apps" list. When a user double-taps the Home button, the list of recently used apps is just that - a list of recently used app. It has absolutely nothing at all to with whether the app is fully terminated or suspended in the background.

Calling `exit(0);` simply terminates your app. But it was still recently used so it appears in the list when the user double-taps the Home button.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode edit the info.plist adding the setting "Application does not run in background" with a value of `YES` to make your application exit every time:

[image: xcode's info.plist editor showing UIApplicationExistsOnSuspend]

Setting this will add `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to info.plist:

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<true/>
```